# How to make a textbox in c# winform to accept auto suggestions not only from starting but also from middle or any place if matching

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, autocomplete, textbox, keypress

I have a simple form with a textBox in it which I am trying to make an user friendly Auto-suggest Textbox..

As per the current scenario I am using `AutoCompleteStringCollection`class bywhich I am able to make textbox show suggestions for the word that starts with the particular Text entered in textbox..
But,I want to make my program as like it should show suggestions even when a part of the string coming from database matches the Textbox.Text.

Presently I am able to filter the data coming from DB based on the userInput by using `dataView` .But still I am not able to show output on my front end..

I have tried all textbox events like '`KeyPress`',`KeyDown`,`KeyUp`,`TextChanged` but its not working....

MyCode::

```
         public partial class Form2 : Form
        {
            AutoCompleteStringCollection autoCompletefromDB = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            AutoCompleteStringCollection searchResults = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();


            MyLinqDataContext dtcontext = new MyLinqDataContext();
          //  static string searchChar = "";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DATASERVER\\SQL2K8;Initial Catalog=VTMMedicalContent;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=vtm;Password=M3d!c@l");
            DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
            SqlCommand cmd;
            SqlDataAdapter da;
            DataView dtView;
            public Form2()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "select DiagnosisName from [VTMMedicalContent].[dbo].[DiagnosisMaster]";
                da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dTable);
                dtView = new DataView(dTable);

            }

     //And My KeyPress Event Code..

 private void txtAutoComplete_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
            {
                dtView.RowFilter = dtView.Table.Columns[0].ColumnName + " Like '%" + e.KeyChar + "%'";
                foreach (DataRowView dtViewRow in dtView)
                    searchResults.Add(dtViewRow[0].ToString());

                txtAutoComplete.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
                txtAutoComplete.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                txtAutoComplete.AutoCompleteCustomSource = searchResults;
            }
            //MessageBox.Show("The Elements in searchResult are:" + searchResults.Count);
        }
```

I have the tried writing the same codes in `KeyDown`,`KeyUp`,`TextChanged` events but of no use..:(

It only works on Form_Load but that only shows suggestions that matches the starting point of the word..

Answer (score 0):

[Create an AutoComplete TextBoxControl](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/34785-create-an-autocomplete-textbox-control-in-c#/)

The AutoComplete feature has a couple of quirks that were inherited from its original designed use, the address box of Internet Explorer.  This includes emitting the Enter key when you click on an item in the list.  Pressing Enter in the address box of IE makes it navigate to the entered URL.

There isn't anything you can do about that, the native interface (IAutoComplete2) has very few options to configure the way it works.  It pokes the keystrokes into the text box by faking Windows messages.  Which is one way you can tell the difference, the actual key won't be down.  Something you can check by pinvoking GetKeyState(), like this:
as an example you can mess with this anyway you like

```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter && GetKeyState(Keys.Enter) < 0) {
            Console.WriteLine("Really down");
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern short GetKeyState(Keys key);
```

Comment: This does not fulfill my case at all..It just brings the value from database at Form_Load and shows those values whose First_Letter matches.
But I want to make atleast such a textBox which can show suggestion atleast irrespective of space..
That is if I type 'U' and there is a record 'Transrectal Ultrasound'
It should atleast that..but Presently this code I am not able to do that alsoo..:(

Comment: Rahul Take a look at my answer.. if worse comes to worse you know that you can use a DropDown control it allows for typing as wel, AutoComplete / Suggestions.

Comment: Ya I can definetly do that But Still it cannot give the effect that a textbox can give..so I am trying to look if anybody has done this before and if he/she could help me out...and Thanks for showing the interest but all that you are saying,I have already tried them..You can look up to my question for details..Is there any other thing which can give me some peace.??

Comment: I will post one more option if that doesn't work for you then I am not sure what you can do .Net 4.5 I believe this works but not in .Net3.5-4.0 I will edit my answer with one more thing

Comment: Checkout that new Link at the top of the Answer .. if this doesn't work.. then you will have to Inherit from the control and Override it's functionality to do what it is that you really want.. good luck Rahul

Comment: No it didn't Worked...I believe I need to inherit TextBox base class and write my own functionality..
Let me try and Get back to you..!!

Comment: That's correct.. I believe that I have mentioned that in the previous comments..let us know how this works out Rahul